# Moving ASMX service to WCF basic binding service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have asmx service that look like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.zzz.com/ema/xml/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class AService : System.Web.Services.WebService, IAServiceSoap
```

The IAServiceSoap interface look following

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.zzz.com/ema/xml/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class AService : System.Web.Services.WebService, IAServiceSoap

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "AsmbServiceSoap", Namespace = "http://www.zzz.com/ema/xml/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(SOAPXmlEventEntry))]
public interface IAsmbServiceSoap {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("http://www.zzz.com/ema/xml/Login", RequestNamespace="http://www.zzz.com/ema/xml/", ResponseNamespace="http://www.zzz.com/ema/xml/")]
    void Login(string url, string id, int ClientType, out int ClientID);


}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.zzz.com/ema/xml/")]
public partial class SOAPXmlEventEntry {

    private int datatypeField;

    private string dataField;

    private int idField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int datatype {
        get {
            return this.datatypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.datatypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string data {
        get {
            return this.dataField;
        }
        set {
            this.dataField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The Question is how I move something that looks like this to WCF webservice with basic binding ?

Comment: For starters, you use a different set of attributes: `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract`. And your configuration can now live mostly in the [<system.serviceModel>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354.aspx) in your `app.config`.

Comment: But how I set all those namespaces ?

Comment: You set the namespace in the attributes, see http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2010/11/10/WCF_service_namespaces

Answer (score 2):

I mocked up what your service would look like if implemented in WCF using a console application.  As long as you are using .NET 4.0, WCF's simplified configuration will take care of creating the endpoints for your service host.  Since the host's base url is based on the http protocol, "basicHttpBinding" will be used as the default binding.

For the client code, all you need to do is add a service reference using the URL that was used to create the ServiceHost.  In this case, I added a service reference and put it inside the namespace, "AService".

Host code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace WcfHost
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.zzz.com/ema/xml/")]
    public interface IAsmbServiceSoap
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Login(string url, string id, int ClientType, out int ClientID); 
    }

    public class AService : IAsmbServiceSoap
    {
        #region IAsmbServiceSoap Members

        public void Login(string url, string id, int ClientType, out int ClientID) {
            ClientID = 100;
            // do work
        }

        #endregion
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(AService), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/AService"));

            ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true };
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);

            serviceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Open for communication.  Press ENTER to close.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            serviceHost.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfClient
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            AService.AsmbServiceSoapClient client = new AService.AsmbServiceSoapClient();

            int clientId = client.Login("http://www.someurl.com", "test", 1);

            Console.WriteLine(clientId);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```